# Floating point integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, floating-point

Trying to make a small script to calculate the incrementally increasing value of a base number by 2%.
Having trouble with, I think, the way I'm handling the floating point.
The script should calculate each number up to a preset value, but it just goes on infinitely.

```
    require 'bigdecimal'


def multiplication sum, count
    print "Original Sum: #{sum}\n"
    until sum == 100 do

        float = BigDecimal('1.02')

        next_sum = (sum * float.round(3))
        print "#{count}: #{next_sum}\n"

        count += 1
        sum = next_sum
    end
end

multiplication 2, 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is looping until sum is exactly 100, which might not happen if it jumps from a value less to a value greater. Change the loop condition to this:

```
until sum >= 100 do
```

Also, "floating point integer" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: perhaps `>=` is even better?

Comment: Hmmm... a floating point value that exactly represents an integer could be called a "floating point integer". But otherwise I agree and another term or description would be better.